# Wordpress order by multiple meta_value_num

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to sort a custom wordpress taxonomy by two custom fields. Currently it displays the book_chapter in the correct order, but the pages are ordered randomly.

1. book_chapter
2. book_page

I've tried putting an array in the 'meta_key' field, which breaks the page...

```
'orderby'    => array(
     'book_chapter' => 'ASC',
     'book_page' => 'ASC'
),
```

This is the base:

```
$book_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'portfolio-category' => 'book',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 120,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => 'book_chapter',
    'order' => ASC,
    'paged' => $paged
);
```

I've already gone through dozens of pages of solutions on this site, and others.  I'm a little rusty with WordPress and about to jump out the window.  Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters provides examples, one of those should cover your use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
$book_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'portfolio-category' => 'book',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 120,
    'paged' => $paged,

    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'chapter_sort' => array(
            'key' => 'book_chapter',
            'type' => NUMERIC
        ),
        'page_sort' => array(
            'key' => 'chapter_verse',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            'type' => NUMERIC
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'chapter_sort' => 'ASC',
        'page_sort' => 'ASC',
    ),
    );
}
```

The code works.  Unfortunately, the page does not display exactly as intended due to data entry issues.

chapter_verse is recorded as a string and not a number.  Then the string is sometimes recorded as 1-7 (for multiple pages).

But the code works.

Thank you for all the assistance.